# No permission to copy files from my machine to WSL using \\WSL$\

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Yesterday I was able to copy files from Windows to my WSL machine using `\\WSL$\home\user\proj`

I could also open new files (all from my Windows Explorer).

Today, however, I was trying to do same but I got error about needing permission, "Access Denied", and I can't find the reason for this.

From the WSL instance, I can access the files on my Windows drive (`/mnt/c`).

Any recommendations?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What account owns this folder?

Comment: @harrymc can you please tell me how to check the account owns ?

Comment: From inside Ubuntu bash (`ls -l`).

Comment: @harrymc from ubuntu i know how to do it - but from windows to WSL i need to do something else ( on ubuntu its -rwxrwxrwx )

Comment: I have to ask, but have you tried a Windows reboot?  Or a `wsl --shutdown`?  Or both?  It sounds like one of the processes may have been started as Admin somehow.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds of course i try reboot and also shutdown

Comment: @Yanshof Ok, so unlikely to be running as a different user unless settings changed in Windows somehow, which would be unlikely.  And you've ruled out permissions on the WSL side of things.  So maybe something in the 9P server, but I don't know what it could be.

Comment: @Yanshof Can you try installing a different distro and see if you can access the files in it through `\\wsl$\`?  That might help determine where we should be looking for the problem, at least.

Comment: @Yanshof Also, I just re-read your statement, and it's not clear to me whether you mean a `wsl --shutdown` or a Windows shutdown.  Note that a `wsl --shutdown` can sometimes re-initialize some things that don't seem to get reset on a normal Windows shutdown.  I'd give that a shot just-in-case.  Long shot, but easy enough to try if you haven't already.

Answer (score -1):

By default you can move any file from any drive of Windows to only `/home/user/` directory using Windows Explorer.
This default behavior with `home` directory, seems to be the same in both WSL versions (see my comment below).

Another way is to broaden permissions of the destination Linux folder, like:

```
sudo chmod 777 destinationFolder
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  I appreciate your desire to help.  However, respectfully, your answer appears to me to be wrong in almost every way.  First, the Ask Ubuntu answer you linked to was specifically about WSL1 and copying directly into the WSL1 overlay filesystem.  You *can* copy to any Windows directory where the *default user* of WSL has permission.  Second, permissions for *Windows* directories (which this user asked about) are determined primarily by those inherited from the parent directory, unlike Linux.

Comment: Third, the `chmod` will have no effect on a Windows directory under WSL by default.  You would have to set `metadata` in your `/etc/wsl.conf` in order for this to have any effect, and even then you would have to have permissions to the *Windows* directory (which seems to be the root issue here).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds 1. This answer has the WSL2 tag. I have WSL2. I had the same error as OP and tested all the steps from my answer on my machine. If something works the other way on your WSL2 please leave a comment. 2. I added the link to that answer to refer to the author of the original solution which I used myself to solve my problem with my WSL2.

Comment: I added some edits to clarify my answer. If you consider the link to that, likely WSL1, question still confusing and better be removed please let me know.

Comment: Thank you - I really do think that the reference to the Ask Ubuntu answer needs to be removed, as that information is just wrong.  It's what first caused me to zero in on the answer. You can certainly copy into other directories, as long as you have permission (which you even demonstrate).  However, I did confuse the *direction* of the copy here, and for that I apologize.  This question, and your answer, is about copying *from* Windows *to* Linux.  So I am sure that this worked for you, assuming you didn't have Linux permissions to the folder in the first place.

Comment: That said, (a) be careful changing permissions on directories - If you don't have access under Ubuntu, then you normally aren't *supposed* to change that. (b) Also, keep in mind that we determined in the comments of this question that the user *did* have Linux permissions to the target directory (see [`-rwxrwxrwx`](/questions/1709121/no-permission-to-copy-files-from-my-machine-to-wsl-using-wsl/1832768?noredirect=1#comment2634321_1709121). Trust me, a few experienced WSL users tried to help the OP here, but we came away at a loss for why it wasn't working in this particular case. :-/

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1384658/781008. The question there doesn't mention a specific WSL version, but considering it was asked Jun 26, 2018 and WSL2 was released [June 2019][1] it should imply WSL1. Nevertheless, I observed the same behavior with `home` directory, and the the same error as OP, on WSL2.

Comment: What directory were you trying to copy to in WSL2?